# How do I rotate text vertically in a Google Slides table cell?

Tags: google-slides

I'm using Google Slides. I would like to be able to add vertical text into a table cell. Microsoft Powerpoint provides this capability. See the screenshot below. How can I do this same action in Google Slides? I searched through all(?) the menu and formatting options.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here steps to create vertical text in Google Slides:

1. Add shape with some text to your slide: [image]
2. Select menu option *Format - Format options* [image]
3. In "Format options" sidebar, you need to look for "Size and rotation" section, set Rotation Angle to `270`: [image]

Your text is vertical now!

Comment: How do I get vertical text in a *table cell*?

Comment: There is no rotation for cells available but you can add vertical text shape over that will look like a cell